# Wrapping linq-to-sql function signatures

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, linq-to-sql, stored-functions

I have a stored function, such:

```
CREATE FUNCTION RegionContains
(
    @RegionX float, @RegionY float, @RegionRadius float,
    @ObjectX float, @ObjectY float
)
RETURNS bit
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @IsContained bit
    DECLARE @ObjectRadius real
    SELECT @ObjectRadius = SQRT(POWER(@ObjectX - @RegionX, 2) + POWER(@ObjectY - @RegionY, 2))

    IF @ObjectRadius <= @RegionRadius
        RETURN 1
    RETURN 0

END
GO
```

It takes 5 float parameters -- but the thing is, I have objects in my C# project which represent these values.

So I open up visual studio and drag the stored function into the DBML designer, and I get a magical function signature which has all of these `double` parameters. Is there a way to create a wrapper for this that won't break when I update the DBML? I want to create a function which takes two typed arguments, that extracts the relevant values from those objects and then sends them to the stored procedure -- while still being allowed to call that wrapper function from a linq query. Does VS support this?

Comment: Why would the wrapper break when you update the DBML?

Comment: Well, I thought mucking around in the generated code would work, but it would be overwritten every time the code was re-generated, wouldn't it?

Comment: You'll have to add any wrappers as a partial class. You will have to change the wrapper if you change the dbml, but the callers of your wrapper should be able to remain unchanged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double-click the designer. A C# source file be created that wont be overwritten.

All generated classes are marked partial, so you can just add your wrapper/helper functions in there. This is quite a common practice, and I tend to use it a lot.

**Update**

Depending on the use case of functions, a wrapper might not work in Linq2SQL queries. If this is what you are after, let me know. I'll delete my answer.

Comment: Yeah, I want to use the wrapper in a linq2sql query. But a linq2sql callable method _is_ created in the generated source file, so there must be some way to make it, no?

Comment: @Carson Myers: You can try, but I suspect the function wont be 'inlined' into the query, thus having to resort to Linq to Object, pretty much defeating the point (and adding a lot of unnecessary  overhead).